# Colour coding data points by numeric value on PCA Biplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I have plotted some different types of PCA biplot and basically want to combine them.

I have this plot with the points colour coded by category
[image]

The code for it is as follows:

```
fviz_pca_biplot(lrr.pca, 
                # Fill individuals by groups
                geom.ind = "point",
                pointshape = 21,
                pointsize = 2.5,
                fill.ind = factor(logresponseduration$stressor_group),
                col.ind = "black",
                legend.title = list(fill = "Categories"),
                repel = TRUE) +
  ggpubr::fill_palette("jco") +      # Indiviual fill color
  ggpubr::color_palette("npg")
```

And then this plot

[image]

Using the following code

```
fviz_pca_ind(lrr.pca, col.ind = logresponseduration$log_response_ratio,
             gradient.cols = c("blue", "red"),
             legend.title = "Cont.Var")
```

I also want the gradient points to be then grouped by category:

[image]

Code:

```
fviz_pca_biplot(lrr.pca, 
                col.ind = factor(logresponseduration$stressor_group), palette = "jco", 
                addEllipses = TRUE, label = "var",
                col.var = "black", repel = TRUE,
                legend.title = "Pressure Group")
```

So I want my final output to be the first plot but with the data points colour coded by log response value like in the second plot, and then to be grouped by their category like the third plot.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You can set a separate colour coding for the ellipses like so: `fviz_pca_biplot(..., habillage = logresponseduration$stressor_group)`. To enable others an in-depth examination of the question, please [supply sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e. g. by pasting the output of `dput(small_subset_of_your_data)`.